# Pfaffian Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solve the Pfaffian Equation below:

$$(yz-1)dx+((z-x)x)dy+(1-xy)dz=0$$

I have tried to find the determinant, and it is $0$. So it is integrable. I let $z$ to be a constant. After I'm having problems solving it.

Comment: Do you have an approach that you generally use or have tried to use to solve this problem? Or are you just stuck after determining integrability?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by finding "the determinant." Please explain. And why are you letting $z$ be constant? Please post a lot more details. Also, do you understand differential forms?

Comment: So, it's been over a week. Have you read the answers? If you're done with the question, please accept one of the answers so that this question will not remain on the unanswered list.

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted one of the answers.

Answer (score 10):

Alexander gave a perfectly fine solution, but here is the general approach you should follow if the answer doesn't "leap out" at you. There are also more elegant approaches (due to Sophus Lie, of Lie group theory) if you can spot a group that leaves the differential equation invariant.

We have the Pfaffian system $\omega = 0$ (where $\omega$ is a $1$-form, here on $\Bbb R^3$). If $d\omega = 0$, then we know from multivariable calculus how to find a potential function $f$ so that $df=\omega$. If $d\omega\ne 0$ but $\omega\wedge d\omega = 0$, then the differential equation is in fact integrable and this means that there is an integrating factor $\mu$: Namely, there is nonvanishing function $\mu$ so that $d(\mu\omega)=0$.  Since
$$d(\mu\omega) = \mu\,d\omega + d\mu\wedge\omega,$$
we want to solve
$$d\omega + \frac{d\mu}{\mu}\wedge\omega = 0,\quad\text{or}\quad
d(\log\mu)\wedge\omega = -d\omega.$$
Comparing the $dx\wedge dy$, $dz\wedge dx$, and $dy\wedge dz$ coefficients on both sides will give you a linear system of equations for the partial derivatives of $\log\mu$, and you can use standard linear algebra to solve a $3\times 3$ system of linear equations for those partial derivatives. Since we are guaranteed a solution, we will be able to integrate $\partial(\log\mu)/\partial x = P$, $\partial(\log\mu)/\partial y = Q$, $\partial(\log\mu)/\partial z = R$ for the function $\log\mu$.

**EDIT**: With thanks to @AntonioJPan, the error in one of the equations has been corrected.

In this particular problem, the equations are (letting $g=\log\mu$ because I'm getting tired of typing)
\begin{align*}
x(z-x)\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} +(1-yz)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}  & =2x \\
(1-xy)\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} +(1-yz)\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} &= 2y \\
(1-xy)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} + x(x-z)\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} &= 2x,
\end{align*}
and standard linear algebra gives us a particular solution
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac {2y}{xy-1}, \quad \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = \frac {2x}{xy-1}, \quad \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}=0.$$
Wasn't that convenient? Now we immediately get $g(x,y,z)=\log(xy-1)^2$, so $\mu(x,y,z)=(xy-1)^2$.

However, as @Antonio suggested, if we look at the general solution of this system of equations, we see that $dg$ will need to be a functional multiple of our original $1$-form $\omega$. In hindsight, this is obvious, as adding any functional multiple $\lambda\omega$ to $dg$ contributes $\lambda\omega\wedge\omega = 0$ to the equation. Indeed, this is just back to the original problem. However, since $\omega$ is nonvanishing off the curve $x=z=1/y$, we can argue that any other solution $h$ of $dh=\lambda\omega$ must satisfy $dh\wedge dg=0$, and so $h$ is a function of $g$.

Comment: What you have given is only a neccesary condition for the integrating factor, but not sufficient. In fact, your system has infinite solutions, and not all of them correspond to partial derivatives of a certain g. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AntonioJPan The Frobenius Theorem says the condition is necessary and sufficient. I do not follow the rest of your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain very well. Frobenius theorem is necessary and sufficient, indeed. But what I think is that your linear equations system is only a necessary condition to find the $g=log(\mu)$. In fact, when you solve your linear equations system, you obtain infinite solutions, and not all of them correspond to partial derivatives of a certain $g$. I wish I was wrong, because I need to find this integrating factor working in my own problem... So, hopefully, you can elighten me. Thanks.

Comment: How do you get infinitely many solutions? Off a certain hypersurface, the determinant is non-vanishing.

Comment: I have just checked that in your 3x3 system there is a mistake. The second equation must be $(1-x y) \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+(1-yz) \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}=2 y$, and this way the determinant vanishes everywhere. So you get infinitely many solutions...

Comment: Of course you're correct, and I've edited appropriately. Thanks for catching my error.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Unfortunately, I see there is no general procedure to find $g$, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

To start, I'm assuming that we're working with $x,y,z\in\Bbb R$. As a consequence, closed and exact forms are exactly the same, i.e.

$$ \text d\omega = 0 \Leftrightarrow \omega = \text d\alpha $$

for some form $\alpha$.

Now, if

$$\omega = (yz-1)\text dx + x(z-x)\text dy + (1-xy)\text dz $$

we can see that

$$ \text d\omega = -2x \ \text dy\wedge\text dz - 2y \ \text dx\wedge\text dz - 2x \ \text dx\wedge\text dy \neq  0 $$

so $\omega$ is not closed and therefore not exact. This means we need to find $\mu(x,y,z)\neq 0$ such that $\omega/\mu$ is closed, and therefore exact. Then, there will be some $\alpha$ such that $\omega/\mu = \text d \alpha$ and so $\omega = \mu\text d\alpha$. Then the integral surfaces are $\alpha  = c$.

Take $ \mu = (xy-1)^2 $, then $ \text d(\omega/\mu) = 0 $ and so we can integrate to get

$$ \alpha(x,y,z) = \frac{x-z}{xy-1} = c $$

are the integral surfaces, or

$$ z = x + c(1-xy) $$

Comment: Of course. But everyone will ask you how you "guessed" $\mu=(xy-1)^2$. That is the whole point of the exercise. This is like Rudin's analysis book, where the crazy multiples of $\epsilon$ show up; the issue is to learn how to find them and what the strategy is.

Comment: @TedShifrin I agree 100%, but I would be lying if I said I had a general explanation of how I found $\mu$. I've spent the last hour trying to formalize the process to update the answer, but I wanted to at least share the solution with the "mysterious" $\mu$ in the mean time :)

Comment: Well, how did you? I can share a general method (assuming one understands the basics of differential forms).

Comment: @TedShifrin Since $\text d\omega/\omega_z$ is independent of $z$, I suspect that $\mu$ should be independent of $z$. This is a guess but is founded in the similar logic used to find integrating factors for 2D Pfaffian equations, and this is the bit that I'm having trouble proving in general. From there, I just put $\mu(x,y)$ through the calculations, ended up with 3 ODEs for $\mu$ and chose the arbitrary functions so they agreed, and $(xy-1)^2$ popped out.